# Flattening Outlined Data then rebuild Outlines again

Tags: excel, vba, parent, outline

To my fellow peers,

Basically I have an extract of a BOM from a business system which generates an outlined report (no template just pushes the data into an excel sheet). An example of which looks like the below:

[image]

I need to flatten this extract to perform some manipulation is there anyway using the columns shown I can rebuild the Outline groupings again to how it was?

Thankyou

Comment: "rebuild the Outline groupings again to how it was" - how was it?

Comment: How do you think it was? It was bang on lol...............thankyou so much Tim appreciate it buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub SetOutline()

  Dim i As Long

  With [A:A].Cells                        'column containing levels
    For i = 1 To .Count
      If IsEmpty(.Item(i)) Then Exit For  'quit at first blank cell
      .Item(i).EntireRow.OutlineLevel = .Item(i).Value + 1 'set outline
'      .Item(i).EntireRow.ClearOutline    'this would remove the outline
    Next i
  End With

End Sub
```